# Grep for each element of array in a loop and write to newfile with BASH

Tags: bash, for-loop, grep

I am using grep and a for loop to try and search for each element of an array (ids) in a file (4700921_combined_subs.txt) and then write each line to a new file which is named as the search term.  There are multiple occurances of each search term in the file being searched.

Can someone help me decipher what is wrong with my code? It does everything i want except the resultant files are all empty. any ideas?

```
    for i in "${ids[@]}"
        do 
        grep '^$i' 4700921_combined_subs.txt > $i.txt
        done
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use double quotes otherwise shell doesn't expand variables:

```
grep "$i" 4700921_combined_subs.txt > "$i.txt"
```

Comment: Excellent, worked wonders. Thanks a lot - its always the simple things.

Comment: You're welcome. If it woks for you please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this much more efficiently with `awk`. Depending on how you obtain `$ids`, you can probably simplify this. Only two calls, one to `grep`, one to `awk`, are needed. And there's probably a way to avoid the call to `grep`, if I could think of it.

```
grep -f <( printf '%s\n' "${ids[@]}" ) 4700921_combined_subs.txt |
   awk '{f=$1.txt; print >> f }'
```